# How can I create new entry in entity from array in Symfony 4?

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine, entity, entitymanager

This is my array `$data`:

```
array(7) {
  ["form[username]"]=>
  string(4) "test"
  ["form[email]"]=>
  string(11) "test@123.sw"
  ["form[is_active]"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["form[plainPassword][first]"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["form[plainPassword][second]"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["form[id]"]=>
  string(1) "9"
  ["form[_token]"]=>
  string(43) "A"
}
```

I store this data into my existing entity `User` like this:

```
$entity = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(User::class)->find($data['form[id]']);
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$entity->setUsername($data['form[username]']);
$entity->setEmail($data['form[email]']);
$em->flush();
```

This is working well!

But now I actually do not want to update an exicting user, I want to create a new user. This is my approach:

```
      $entity = new User();
      $entity = $data;
      $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
      $entity->setUsername($data['form[username]']);
      $entity->setEmail($data['form[email]']);
      $em->flush();
```

I get the error:

> Call to a member function setUsername() on array

Comment: maybe you should try to remove $entity = $data...

Comment: @Jarla: I've already made the remark on one of your question: You should, preferably, use symfony form to process incoming data and then binding `$data` -> `User` should be trivial. The way you do it is error-prone and without validation...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is recommended to use symfony form types and not the raw data directly. This will save you from nightmares. The same form type will be used for newAction() and editAction() in your controllers.

I post an example for you below:

## Form Type

```
class UserType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('username')
            ->add('email');
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'your User entity reference'
        ));
    }
}
```

## Controller

```
public function newAction(Request $request)
{
    try
    {
        $user = new User();
        $form = $this->createForm('path to your UserType', $user);
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        $form->submit($request->request->all());
        if ($form->isSubmitted())
        {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($user);
            $em->flush();

        //your code
    }
    catch (\Exception $exception)
    {
        // return your exception
    }
}
```

This way, you dont need to set anything explicitly. Data is automatically handled and submitted.

More on this here : https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/forms.html

Comment: Thank you, where exactly do you load in the `$data` array? The data array is coming on from a json request

Comment: Thats the magic of symfony. if your json request has the same elements as that of your formtype then $form->handleRequest($request); will insert data from your json to $user variable automatically.

Comment: What do you put here `path to your UserType`?

Comment: as Route/path of UserType you put `{@inheritdoc}`

Comment: your FormType which I coded above. For Example 
i have a Role..
    $role = new Role();
    $form = $this->createForm(RoleType::class, $role);
 ...

Comment: Wow, I will try now to implement your code into mine, but I guess I will need a while. Looks difficult, but I think it is a good solution. Do you think this is possible with my code? https://textuploader.com/d7fcw

Comment: O my god! This code should be modular (separate formtype and controller functions..) you are unfortunately doing alot of work. 
symfony is beautiful because it saves you from doing a lot of work. 
It is absolutely possible with your code.

Comment: I am working on the implementation of your code. This is the Controller: https://textuploader.com/d7fht and this is the FormController https://textuploader.com/d7fh9 Is the way of implementation correct? I get the error message `syntax error, unexpected 'catch' (T_CATCH)`

Comment: your try doesnt have a catch statement :/

Answer (score 2):

Remove `$entity = $data;` and persist entity.

```
$user = new User();
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$user->setUsername($data['form[username]']);
$user->setEmail($data['form[email]']);
$em->persist($user);
$em->flush();
```